# RShiny not producing plots

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am not able to produce any plots from my Shiny code on the html page. However when I tried the below code on my local system, it produced the plots. The package versions are same at both server and local location.

There are no specific errors on the shiny-server log files.

Code has been copied from one of the tutorial website for ease [from here](http://deanattali.com/blog/building-shiny-apps-tutorial/):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("BC Liquor Store prices"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("priceInput", "Price", 0, 100, c(25, 40), pre = "$"),
      radioButtons("typeInput", "Product type",
                   choices = c("BEER", "REFRESHMENT", "SPIRITS", "WINE"),
                   selected = "WINE"),
      selectInput("countryInput", "Country",
                  choices = c("CANADA", "FRANCE", "ITALY"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("coolplot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1:10)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My output :
[image: output]

What all could be the possible issues here? permission issues? js issues?

Comment: the grey screen is indicative or an error. Try looking at the javascript console for an error message or at the error log of shiny server. (Great tutorial choice by the way! :)

Comment: haha! thanks for the tutorial! how to look at the javascipt console @DeanAttali?

Comment: it's different for every browser and OS. Google for "how to open javascript console <browser> <OS>". Also check shiny server error logs

Comment: @DeanAttali shiny server error logs showed no errors.. and the javascript console gives me this error `{"error":{"code":6,"error":null,"message":"Invalid json-rpc request"}}` which i have no clue about

Comment: I don't know if that message is related. Debugging a shiny server specific problem is unfortunately never fun nor easy. Try removing lines from your app one by one until you find the culprit, that's the best advice I can give you without diving deep into it myself :/